# Remove additional comma without knowing the length of the string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

**My tables**

*MyTable*

```
+----+-------+---------------+
| Id | Title | DependencyIds |
+----+-------+---------------+
```

`DependentIds` contains values like `14;77;120`.

---

*MyDependentTable*

```
+--------------+------+
| DependencyId | Name |
+--------------+------+
```

---

**Background**

I have to select data from `MyTable` with every dependency from `MyDependentTable` separated with a comma.

Expected output:

```
+---------+-------------------------------------+
| Title   | Dependencies                        |
+---------+-------------------------------------+
| Test    | ABC, One-two-three, Some Dependency |
+---------+-------------------------------------+
| Example | ABC                                 |
+---------+-------------------------------------+
```

---

**My query**

```
SELECT t.Title,
    (SELECT ISNULL((
        SELECT DISTINCT
        (
            SELECT dt.Name + '',
                   CASE WHEN DependencyIds LIKE '%;%' THEN ', ' ELSE '' END AS [text()]
            FROM MyDependentTable dt
            WHERE dt.DependencyId IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.fSplitIds(t.DependencyIds, ';'))
            ORDER BY dt.DependencyId
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )), '')) Dependencies
FROM dbo.MyTable t
```

---

**Problem description**

The query works, but adds an additional comma when there are multiple dependencies:

```
+---------+---------------------------------------+
| Title   | Dependencies                          |
+---------+---------------------------------------+
| Test    | ABC, One-two-three, Some Dependency,  |
+---------+---------------------------------------+
| Example | ABC                                   |
+---------+---------------------------------------+
```

I can't use `SUBSTRING(ISNULL(...` because I can't access the length of the string and therefore I'm not able to set the length of the `SUBSTRING`.

Is there any possibility to get rid of that unnecessary additional comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally for group concatenation in Sql Server, people will add *leading* comma and remove it using `STUFF` function but even that looks ugly.

`Outer Apply` method looks neat to do this instead of `correlated sub-query`. In this method we don't have to wrap the `SELECT` query with `ISNULL` or `STUFF`

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.title, 
                Isnull(LEFT(dependencies, Len(dependencies) - 1), '') 
                Dependencies 
FROM   dbo.mytable t 
       OUTER apply (SELECT dt.NAME + ',' 
                    FROM   mydependenttable dt 
                    WHERE  dt.dependencyid IN (SELECT value 
                                               FROM 
                           dbo.Fsplitids(t.dependencyids,';')) 
                    ORDER  BY dt.dependencyid 
                    FOR xml path('')) ou (dependencies)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method using `STUFF`.

```
SELECT  t.Title
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(dt.Name AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
               FROM MyDependentTable dt
               WHERE dt.DependencyId IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.fSplitIds(t.DependencyIds, ';'))
               ORDER BY dt.DependencyId
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') Dependencies
FROM dbo.MyTable  t
```